# IHP - sorting on field in joined tables?

Tags: ihp

Is it possible to sort on a field in a joined table? For instance, if I want something like:

```
(modules, pagination) <- query @Module
    |> innerJoin @User (#userId, #id)
    |> orderByJoinedTable #email
    |> paginate
```

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible. You would need to use a handwritten sql query for this using `sqlQuery`

Comment: Okay thanks, should I make a GitHub issue?

Comment: yes, that would be good